# Executing host command from netezza procedure

Tags: netezza

Is there any option to execute the netezza host commands from inside a stored proc.
I'm trying to execute sendMail command from Netezza proc.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly in stored procedures, no. You can define a [UDX](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.udf.doc/c_udf_user_defined_funcs.html?cp=SSULQD_7.2.0%2F9) that can interact with the host system.